# How do we sort a multi dimensional hash based on the value?

Tags: regex, perl, perl-module, hash-of-hashes

I have an hash which looks like this when I use dumper:

```
{      
 hello => {   
    pqr => {   
     a => 455,
     b => 52,
     c => "hello"
    },
    lmn => {
     a => 3,
     b => 39,
     c => "hi"
    }
 },
 hi => {
    suv => {
     a => 21,
     b => 36,
     c => "well"
    },
    xyz => {
     a => 32,
     b => 56,
     c => "done"
    }
 }
}
```

I would like to sort based on the value of "b".

Output should be like:

> hello.lmn.b = 39    hello.pqr.b = 52
>
> hi.suv.b = 36    hi.xyz.b = 56

Comment: Please post what you have tried and where you failed.

Answer (score 2):

You should use [`sort`](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/sort.html) for sorting lists. In this case the hash is nested so it is iterated at first level keys and then sorted with second level keys according to the values the `b` contains at third level.

```
for my $k1 (keys %hash) {
    for my $k2 (sort {$hash{$k1}{$a}{'b'} <=> $hash{$k1}{$b}{'b'}} keys %{$hash{$k1}}) {
        print "$k1.$k2.b = ",$hash{$k1}{$k2}{'b'}, " ";
    }
    print "\n";
}
```